# getJSON, iteration, display images

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have JSON containing images. It looks like:

```
["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","Thumbs.db","..","." .............]
```

I can access them one by one like:

```
data[0]
data[1]
data[2]
```

However, I would like to dynamically display all these images one above other (in one column) in a specific div. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    updateProfil();

    function updateProfil() {
        $.getJSON("./index_logg1.php", null, processCategory); 
    }   

    function processCategory(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
            // the code ????
        });

        $("#my_user").html('<img src='+ ???? +' />');
        $("#my_user").hide().fadeIn(700);
    }

});
```

EDIT :

Hi,

thank you for your replies.
I am able now to dynamically visualize the images ( with the following code), but the problem is that i want to be able to capture (dynamically) the href value when the image is clicked. (then sent it to php via jquery post)

it displays the values on mouse hovering, but no luck with capturing them when clicked.Nothing seems to be working so far ...

The code:

```
enter code here
    function updateProfil() {
  $.getJSON("./index_logg2.php", null, processCustom); 
   }

function processCustom(data) {
   $.each(data, function(k, v) {
   $(".panel").append('<center><a href="?cust='+  k +'"><img src="images/custom/'+ v +' "title="Click to set it" "></a></center><br />');

   /*
   $(".panel").click(function() {
 var data= ???
   $.post("./index_logg2.php", { data: ??? }, updateProfil ); 
   });
   */

   });
   }
```

Thanks !

Comment: And the question would be?

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery tutorials and API documentation. It has all the information about how to create and add elements: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials, http://api.jquery.com.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `this` inside of `$.each`,

```
function processCategory(data) {

    $.each(data, function(){
       $("#my_user").append("<img src='"+this+"' />");
    });

    $("#my_user").hide().fadeIn(700);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    updateProfil();

    function updateProfil() {

    html="";
    $.getJSON('./index_logg1.php', function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(i) {
            html+='<img src='+ data[i] +' />'
        });

        $("#my_user").html(html);
        $("#my_user").hide().fadeIn(700);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the solution with the best performance, but adding the one after the other ensures images are added instantaneously.

```
    function processCategory(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        $('#my_user').append($('<img>', { src: val, alt: 'pic' }));
      });

      $("#my_user").hide().fadeIn(700);
    }
```